# ROS Kinetic, How to pass a parameter from a launch file to the xacro file

Tags: ros

I'm trying to pass values from the launch file to the xacro model, so I can, for example, launch two robots in a single world but using different topic names or material colors. Is there a way to do this?

I've tried this unsuccessfully: https://answers.ros.org/question/38956/pass-parameters-to-xacro-in-launch-file/

It gives an error: xxx.launch requires the 'ns' arg to be set.

I also see this here: http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/arg  But that only shows how to send parameters from one launch file to another.

Here is my launch file:

```
<launch>


  <!-- these are the arguments you can pass this launch file, for example paused:=true -->
  <arg name="paused" default="false"/>
  <arg name="use_sim_time" default="true"/>
  <arg name="gui" default="true"/>
  <arg name="headless" default="false"/>
  <arg name="debug" default="false"/>
    <arg name="ctopic" default="/stupid/test" />

  <!-- Load the URDF into the ROS Parameter Server -->
  <param name="robot_description"
     command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find mybot_description)/urdf/mybot.xacro' ctopic:=$(arg ns) "/>

  <!-- We resume the logic in empty_world.launch, changing only the name of the world to be launched -->
  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" value="$(find mybot_gazebo)/worlds/mybot.world"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="$(arg debug)" />
    <arg name="gui" value="$(arg gui)" />
    <arg name="paused" value="$(arg paused)"/>
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="$(arg use_sim_time)"/>
    <arg name="headless" value="$(arg headless)"/>
  </include>

  <!-- Run a python script to the send a service call to gazebo_ros to spawn a URDF robot -->
  <node name="urdf_spawner" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" respawn="false" output="screen"
    args="-urdf -model mybot -param robot_description"/>

  <!-- Run RVIZ
  <node name="$(anon rviz)" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="$(find mybot_gazebo)/mybot.rviz" output="screen"/>-->

  <!-- ros_control mybot launch file -->
  <include file="$(find mybot_control)/launch/mybot_control.launch" /> 

</launch>
```

I've tried this in my xacro file:

```
$(arg ctopic)
```

and

```
<xacro:property name="ctopic" value="$(arg ctopic)" />
```

Thanks

Comment: Look at your call to the `xacro`: `ctopic:=$(arg ns)`. You're passing an arg called `ctopic` to contain the value of an arg called `ns`. Do you perhaps mean `ns:=$(arg ctopic)`?

Comment: answered on rosanswers: https://answers.ros.org/question/38956/pass-parameters-to-xacro-in-launch-file/